# Working with two Two-dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested

```py
my_list = [['Chris',33,'JAN'],['Katia',40,'JAN'],['Petunia',54,'JAN'],['Clee',26,'JAN'],['katt',73,'JAN'],['battt',83,'JAN'],['FRIES',59,'FEB'],['GGEEZ',89,'FEB'],['SHEEESH',25,'MAR']]
threshold = [[217, 'JAN'], [104, 'FEB'], [18, 'MAR']]

output: [['Chris','Katia','Petunia','Clee','katt'],['FRIES','GGEEZ'],['SHEEESH']]
```

I want to make a new  list with the first element in the nested array (the names) until the sum of the second elements in the nested array passes the 217 for JAN, 104 for FEB and 18 for MARCH.

I dont know how to do it since both of the lists are  are indented and I find that hard to work with, But it should check it in a loop if my_list[2] == threshold[1] and sum the my_list[1]s until it is greater or equal to threshold[0] than it should go and check if the and check if my_list[2] == threshold[1] (but this time we skip the remaining januaries and check if the february is equal to the mylist and so on, its hard to articulate

Answer (score 1):

```
output = []
for a,b in threshold:
    sum = 0
    curr = []
    for x,y,z in my_list:
        if z == b and sum < a:
            sum += y
            curr.append(x)
    output.append(curr)
```

Comment: sum needs to be reset for each iteration of threshold right?

Comment: From my understanding yes, otherwise I can't see how we will get the names for FEB since its already lower than JAN threshold.

Comment: Thank you Awkward Syntax yours worked perfectly!

Comment: And yeah it dooes reste every month because every month has their own total sales in the real data

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
my_list = [['Chris',33,'JAN'],['Katia',40,'JAN'],['Petunia',54,'JAN'],['Clee',26,'JAN'],['katt',73,'JAN'],['battt',83,'JAN'],['FRIES',59,'FEB'],['GGEEZ',89,'FEB'],['SHEEESH',25,'MAR']]
threshold = [[217, 'JAN'], [104, 'FEB'], [18, 'MAR']]

results = []

for max_num, month in threshold:
    accumulator = []
    count = 0
    for s, num, month_ in my_list:
        if month == month_ and count < max_num:
            accumulator.append(s)
    results.append(accumulator)

print(results)
```

output:

```
[['Chris', 'Katia', 'Petunia', 'Clee', 'katt', 'battt'], ['FRIES', 'GGEEZ'], ['SHEEESH']]
```